# Child reversing output when prematurely killed by parent

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork, signals

This is some pseudo code of what I'm trying to achieve:

fork

in the child, dup2 a output descriptor to a file then exec a different program

in parent, kill the child after a period of time

The problem is though that after I kill the child the output file is empty even though the child has written to it at some stage. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to wait for the child but I also don't want it to reverse what it's already written to file.

Comment: That `kill` does exactly what you want it do to (sends `SIGINT` to `childpid`). What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Oh ok. I'm dup2ing a file descriptor to a file for my child process to write to and then I exec in my child process. This works but my problem is that as soon as I kill the child the output file becomes empty. If I don't kill it then it has the right output from my child process but if I do then it has nothing (even though it would have already written stuff to the file before I kill it). Do I need to tell the child to close the output stream before I kill it or something?

Comment: please edit your question (and it's title) to explain exactly what is happening, and what you want to happen. Not waiting for the child to finish correctly doesn't make sens if you need it to finish doing something.

Comment: I don't want to wait for it to finish but I also don't want it to reverse what it's already done (written to a file) so I don't understand what it's doing.

I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your child dies as a result of a signal, it won't flush any buffers, that's why you don't see any output. There are solutions for this

- Handle the signal and flush the buffers
- Use unbuffered I/O (should avoid this)
- Synchronize the child and the parent (using the pipe) (so that the parent knows it's safe to kill the child).

Of course, the third option is rather silly: the child signaling the parent could be replaced by simply exiting.

**Edit**
*In light of edited question and comments*

`stdio` (printf, fwrite etc.), for reasons of I/O efficiency uses some buffers. That is, when you do a simple write, the low-level operation doesn't happen right away. The data is copied to some buffer and later, when the library deems it necessary (full buffers or something else) the buffers will be flushed - stuff is going to be written.

Now, when a program calls `exit(3)` (normal process termination) on of the things that happens is that `stdio` buffers are flushed. If a program dies as a result of a signal, `stdio` buffers aren't flushed and the memory is simply claimed by the OS.

If you don't have control over the programs you `exec` (say you're a shell) you can't be sure they will do their thing if you kill them. That is, it's not your responsibility. If however you *do* have control over them (you said something about a pipe) you can simply signal through the pipe some sequence that will make the children call `exit(3)`.

Comment: Thanks! Which of these do I want to do if I don't want to change the program that is being exec'd?

Comment: @Sam Well, since you don't want to modify the program that you `exec`, it's hard to say. *Why* don't you want it to simply exit normally ? If it shouldn't exit normally, how do you know when it's time to kill it ?

Comment: I need the user to be able to send signals to it to kill it but I don't want it to erase what it's already done. To be quite honest, I don't really understand why it is erasing what it's already done. 

Can you explain more about flushing the buffers? Why is this necessary? Can I do it in the parent?

Comment: @Sam I will explain once you tell us why you need to kill it.

Comment: I will be honest and say it's for a university assignment. I'm making a program that runs a whole lot of other programs and needs to be able to kill (and then reap) any children it has spawned that have not already died when it shuts down itself.

Comment: Why do you say that the child is "eras[ing] what it's already done"?  If in fact you are seeing data in the file that is truncated when the child is killed, that would be remarkable.  How do you know the child has done anything at all before you kill it?

Comment: @William because if I comment out the kills and just leave the children running when I exit from my program then when I look at the files they have the correct output. I understand that it's not actually erasing though after cnicutar's explanation and that does make sense.




I'm still taking it all in and am trying to work out what the instructor wants us to do. Basically the program I'm trying to kill prints something out and then just hangs around until it gets a SIGKILL but it is still expected that the message it prints out will be in its out file when my program exits.

Comment: Wait, I think I might know what the problem is.. I have a waitpid loop to reap but I'm using the WNOHANG option. If I use it without that option does it try to terminate the process? Or will it just wait infinitely if the program is in an infinite loop?

Comment: So you **do** use `wait` :) `wait` will never kill a process, `WNOHANG` means it will return immediately if no process has terminated.

Comment: Yep! I just asked my instructor and it turns out the program does already flush its buffers on a signal.. the issue was that I was SIGINTing it and then SIGKILLing it without waiting. I added a sleep(1) in and it worked as expected.. very frustrating as I had no way of knowing that I needed to do that! Thanks for your help though, really appreciated. I understand what's happening beneath the scenes now too which is always handy. :)

Comment: @Sam Oh, so the programs you exec already flush their buffers in their handler. I see :)

Comment: @Sam: Rather than `sleep(1)`, the correct way would be to first block `SIGCHLD` with `sigprogmask`, then send `SIGINT`, use `sigtimedwait` to wait (with a 1 second timeout) for `SIGCHLD`, use `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` to see if it's exited, and if not, send `SIGKILL`. This way you avoid introducing unnecessary delays into your program - delays which users surely hate!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the input R!